# Convert character date to date format

Tags: r

I have date in character vector. I need to convert it to date format.

For example :

```
Month = "202005"
```

Output should be `May-20`. It should be in date format so that I can use to filter some dates. Similarly `201912` should return `Dec-19`

Comment: Without the `zoo` package, you can try transforming `Month` into something that is acceptable by `as.Date`, for example `as.Date(paste(substring(Month,1,4), substring(Month,5), "01", sep = "-"))`

Answer (score 1):

`zoo` has a function called `yearmon()`.

```
library(zoo)
month <- "202005"
as.yearmon(month, "%Y%m")
# "May 2020"
```